# Does async Task method never throw?

Tags: c#, exception, async-await

It appears that an async method always captures its exceptions into a `Task` that the method returns including those thrown *before* the first `await`". In other words the following code works as intended and no exceptions are thrown until the line with `Task.WhenAll`:

```
async Task DoSomethingAsync(int i)
{
       if (i == 2) throw new InvalidOperationException();
       await Task.Delay(1000);
} 

...

var tasks = new List<Task>();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
     var t = DoSomethingAsync(i); // no awaits here
     tasks.Add(t); 
} 


// Wait for all tasks
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);   // throws  InvalidOperation when the other 2 tasks succeed
```

The question:

Is this behavior of async methods part of the language spec or it is just the way it was implemented in the current version of .NET? Can I rely on this behavior in my code?

Comment: In addition to Jon Skeet's answer below, Stephen Cleary talks about this behaviour briefly in this [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/10/a-tour-of-task-part-5-wait.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this behavior of async methods part of the language spec

Yes it is. From section 10.15.1 of the C# 5 specification:

> - If the function body terminates as the result of an uncaught exception (§8.9.5) the exception is recorded in the return task which is put into a faulted state.

Section 10.15.2 gives details of async methods returning `void`:

> If the return type of the async function is void, evaluation differs from the above in the following way: Because no task is returned, the function instead communicates completion and exceptions to the current thread’s synchronization context. The exact definition of synchronization context is implementation-dependent, but is a representation of “where” the current thread is running. The synchronization context is notified when evaluation of a void-returning async function commences, completes successfully, or causes an uncaught exception to be thrown.

Admittedly I don't think it *explicitly* says that the call itself doesn't throw, but I believe that is the intended interpretation of the spec.

If you *want* a method to throw if (say) preconditions aren't met, but then use normal async behaviour, you can take the same approach as is common for iterator blocks:

```
public Task Foo(int someParameter)
{
    // Check preconditions here and throw - note that this isn't an
    // async method, so the exceptions will be thrown synchronously.
    return FooImpl(someParameter);
}

private async Task FooImpl(int someParameter)
{
    // Assume everything is valid now.
    // Normal async method implementation.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon! Isolating this behavior using a wrapper is in fact what I had to do in few places as I was refactoring old code written before .NET 4.5.